# How can I limit object from an array in svelte

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, svelte, sveltekit

I'm searching in svelte documentation about this, but I can't get it.

What I want is to show only 4 objects from an array

For example:

```js
let data = [
    {id:1, name: 'John'},
    {id:2, name: 'Peter'},
    {id:3, name: 'Stev'},
    {id:4, name: 'Clar'},
    {id:5, name: 'Eyad'},
    {id:6, name: 'Vector'}
]
```

Then the results only show

```
John
Peter
Stev
Clar
```

Seems like ReactJS as you just add `index` in `map()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`each` block](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks) allows you to iterate over an array and gives you two variables: the current element as its index in the array. You can combine this with an `if` block to check if the index is within the range you'd like:

[Svelte REPL Link](https://svelte.dev/repl/abb4498710f54fe699765c36f35bb871?version=4.1.1)

```html
<script>
    let data = [
    {id:1, name: 'John'},
    {id:2, name: 'Peter'},
    {id:3, name: 'Stev'},
    {id:4, name: 'Clar'},
    {id:5, name: 'Eyad'},
    {id:6, name: 'Vector'}
];
</script>

{#each data as person, index}
    {#if index < 4}
        <p>
            {person.name}
        </p>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

Alternatively, you could first use `.splice()` first and forgo the `if` block:

[Svelte REPL link](https://svelte.dev/repl/700c1dbae6194b7191212977a82c90ad?version=4.1.1)

```html
<script>
    let data = [
    {id:1, name: 'John'},
    {id:2, name: 'Peter'},
    {id:3, name: 'Stev'},
    {id:4, name: 'Clar'},
    {id:5, name: 'Eyad'},
    {id:6, name: 'Vector'}
];
</script>

{#each data.slice(0, 4) as person}
    <p>
        {person.name}
    </p>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just apply a [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), either in the template in `{#each}` or just directly in the script. You can use any valid JS in the script block.

```html
{#each data.slice(0, 4) as ...}
```

```js
let data = [/* ... */].slice(0, 4)
```

If the `data` can change and you always want the first four elements, you can use a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive):

```js
$: slicedData = data.slice(0, 4)
```

Note that if the elements can change in ways other than just appending elements, an `{#each}` over the array should also use a key ([see docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each)).